# Averaging an image on CUDA using atomicAdd gives inconsistent results

Tags: image-processing, graphics, parallel-processing, cuda, computer-vision

I'm averaging the intensity of an image as a simple test case for a larger problem. But the result that I get is slightly different every time I run it. Conversely, if I run the same algorithm sequentially on CPU the result is static. Let's look at the code on GPU,

```
//util.cu
__global__ void avgImageDevice(float3 *avg, float3 *d_colorImageRGB, unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
{
    const unsigned int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    const unsigned int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if (x >= width || y >= height) return;

    atomicAdd(&avg->x, d_colorImageRGB[y*width + x].x);
    atomicAdd(&avg->y, d_colorImageRGB[y*width + x].y);
    atomicAdd(&avg->z, d_colorImageRGB[y*width + x].z);
}

extern "C" void avgImage(float3 *avg, float3 *d_colorImageRGB, unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
{
    const int T_PER_BLOCK = 16;
    const dim3 blockSize((width + T_PER_BLOCK - 1) / T_PER_BLOCK, (height + T_PER_BLOCK - 1) / T_PER_BLOCK);
    const dim3 gridSize(T_PER_BLOCK, T_PER_BLOCK);

    avgImageDevice << <blockSize, gridSize >> >(avg, d_colorImageRGB, width, height);
}
```

And the CPU implementation is as follow,

```
//main.cpp

#include <vector_types.h>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <cuda_runtime.h> 
#include <string>
extern "C" void avgImage(float3 *avg, float3 *d_colorImageRGB, unsigned int width, unsigned int height);

int main()
{
    for(int k = 0 ; k < 100 ;++k)
    {
        //Initialization
        Mat Image;
        float3 avgCPU = make_float3(0, 0, 0);
        float3 avgGPU = make_float3(0, 0, 0);
        std::string filenameImage("/foo.jpg");
        Image = imread(filenameImage, -1);
        Image.convertTo(Image, CV_32FC3, 1.0f / 255);

        //Copy to GPU global memory
        cutilSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(d_albedoMapFilteredFloat3, Image.data, sizeof(float) * 3 * Image.size().width * Image.size().height, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

        //Average on CPU
        for (int x = 0; x < Image.size().width; ++x)
            for (int y = 0; y < Image.size().height; ++y)
            {
                Vec3f intensity = Image.at<Vec3f>(y, x);
                avgCPU += make_float3(intensity.val[0], intensity.val[1], intensity.val[2]);
            }
        avgCPU /= Image.size().width * Image.size().height;


        //Average on GPU
        float3 *d_avg;
        cutilSafeCall(cudaMalloc(&d_avg, sizeof(float3)));
        cutilSafeCall(cudaMemset(d_avg, 0, sizeof(float3)));
        avgImage(d_avg, d_albedoMapFilteredFloat3, Image.size().width, Image.size().height);
        cutilSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(&avgGPU, d_avg, sizeof(float3), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        avgGPU /= Image.size().width * Image.size().height;

        //Following values are consant across the iterations
        printf("AVG CPU r: %.10f, g: %.10f, b: %.10f\n", avgCPU.x, avgCPU.y, avgCPU.z);

        //Following values are different at every iteration
        printf("AVG GPU r: %.10f, g: %.10f, b: %.10f\n", avgGPU.x, avgGPU.y, avgGPU.z);
    }
}
```

So each pair of following lines should match, and be static. But they do not match and GPU results are not static.

```
AVG CPU r: 0.6326226592, g: 0.6762236953, b: 0.6836426258
AVG GPU r: 0.6325752139, g: 0.6762712002, b: 0.6835504174
AVG CPU r: 0.6326226592, g: 0.6762236953, b: 0.6836426258
AVG GPU r: 0.6325753927, g: 0.6762660146, b: 0.6835544705
AVG CPU r: 0.6326226592, g: 0.6762236953, b: 0.6836426258
AVG GPU r: 0.6325772405, g: 0.6762678027, b: 0.6835457087
AVG CPU r: 0.6326226592, g: 0.6762236953, b: 0.6836426258
AVG GPU r: 0.6325744987, g: 0.6762621403, b: 0.6835452914
AVG CPU r: 0.6326226592, g: 0.6762236953, b: 0.6836426258
AVG GPU r: 0.6325761080, g: 0.6762756109, b: 0.6835403442
AVG CPU r: 0.6326226592, g: 0.6762236953, b: 0.6836426258
AVG GPU r: 0.6325756311, g: 0.6762655973, b: 0.6835408211
```

I have a GTX 960, CUDA 6.5, and Windows 7. Is this a data-race issue? To the best of my knowledge, `atomicAdd` is not reported to have any problem with global memory.

Comment: Do you actually initialize the values you pass and atomically increment?

Comment: Yes. I ensured that I am initializing everything.

Comment: So how are we supposed to know the problem when you haven't posted an [MCVE]? I am just supposed to guess?

Comment: Modified accordingly.

Comment: Did you verify assembly to ensure your cpu operations are in fp32 and not fp64?

Comment: But despite the type of CPU operations, the GPU results should be static across the iterations.

Comment: The `sizeof(float)` is 4 so it's fp32.

Comment: Using float does not necessarily mean the cpu will perform operations using 32 bits IEEE-754 norm operations, it depends on the compilation flags.

Comment: Block scheduling is not guaranteed to be the same across executions. Hence slightly different results.

Comment: But this is not the matter of scale of the error. Averaging the image is reducing the error by itself. If I do another operation other than averaging a larger error can be expected. If the data-race cannot be avoided with atomicAdd then what's the use of it?

Comment: because without atomic add your results could be much much different.  Try it!  The difference between `0.6325752139` and `0.6325753927` is something like 1 ULP difference.  Without atomic add you might get a GPU result of 0, or 0.3, or something like that.

Comment: What's the reason for this difference? Whatever operation atomic add is doing, if no data-race is involved, it should be static across the iterations. What is causing this fluctuation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a data race.

Floating point addition is commutative:

```
a + b == b + a
```

But it is **not** associative; there are a,b,c such that:

```
(a + b) + c != a + (b + c)
```

The different orderings of the individual additions (in particular the way they are associated) will give different results.

Comment: This makes sense actually. Considering the average intensity as a summation of nodes of a tree from bottom up, then in the GPU, this tree looks different in every iteration. Since each thread is running in a different scope of time.

Answer (score 3):

Result may depend on the scheduling order of the threads. Indeed, depending on the image size, values in components, the resulting average may slightly differ from a run to another, though all values would be correct. If num different from a run to another, there is a most likely a problem in other parts of the code. If num is the same, all your results are correct up to IEEE-754 norm.